# Which better? Write all scripts on timeline or write it partially on `.as` file?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm going to create a flash game. But I don't know which way for me to write my scripts.

Is it better if I write script part by part and by object so every object has they own script .. or write all of those object's script on single timeline?

Comment: The best way to go would be to _not_ write a Flash game. This technology is quite dead, find something else like JavaScript/HTML5 or Unity...

Comment: I know it's not really an answer to your question, but @AlexandreVaillancourt is absolutely correct.  Aside from the fact that Flash is a dead or dying platform, it's also fraught with security issues that appear very frequently.

Comment: Plenty of good stuff can still be done with flash. You can compile AIR apps for mobile platforms, for instance. If you want to write as3, go for it. I'd recommend using classes and separate .as files when it makes sense and DITCH the timeline coding. The timeline is basically for animators, not programmers. My 2cents

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally go with individual AS files. Timeline coding is very AS2 and is more for animators as someone else stated.

If your game gets complicated, breaking classes out into AS files will definitely help with organization as well. I recommend an editor like flashdevelop over doing it in the Flash/Animate IDE

Answer (score -1):

.as files and use more powerful libraries, such as starling and citrus and don't use vector graphics, it's taxing on the CPU.

Comment: Welcome to Gamedev.StackExchange! We generally prefer more informative answers here, so this post would be better if you edited the answer to explain some reasons *why* you'd recommend using .as files, or why those particular libraries would be useful. Sharing this helps other users make informed decisions about their projects.